# How to get "middle click to lower window" working again?

Tags: gnome, touchpad, 22.04, wayland

I've recently upgraded from 20.04 and now "middle click to lower window" does not work anymore. I use the `gnome-tweaks` package to configure this setting via the "Window Titlebars" menu under "Titlebar Actions" -> "Middle-Click". The option is set to "Lower". When using the middle-click on the titlebar nothing happens.

When I set the option to "Minimize" or "Menu", then the window is minimized or a menu is shown, respectively. So middle-click does work on the titlebar. And middle-clicking works outside of this context as well. How can I get this working on 22.04? Could this been an issue with gnome-tweaks not updated to reflect gnome 42 changes? I correct answer could be its not possible, but it would need a good convincing explanation as to why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is yet [another feature lost with Wayland](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1349225). Log out, then before logging in, select "Ubuntu on Xorg" to have the functionality back.

Comment: Do you have any documentation to back this up or just assuming?

Comment: Yes. It could also be that gnome-tweaks is setting a gconf property that was renamed in the newer gnome. But googling again with "wayland" popups up with [many links](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1349225) suggesting its a [wayland issue](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=767967) that [can't be resolved](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/wayland-devel/2020-May/041445.html).

Comment: So my answer is correct, then. Mind that I tested this before answering. Thanks for the search: I will add the link for future reference.

Comment: @crass Please accept this answer as the correct solution. Vanadium - upvoting because no one else did :)

Comment: The "new" firefox snap manages its own title bar. Nice, but it seems that it doesn't follow the gconf property.

Comment: @FrankM You can go back to the old style title bar by changing one of the settings in about:config and then it will act like all other windows.